# Unobtrusive validation doesn't work with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have View with Model1 where I put `Ajax.BeginForm()` and in this View i have PartialView with Model2 where i put `Ajax.BeginForm()`. So only in first form working `unobtrusive validation`. Why only in first form working validation?

**first View**

```
@model Model1

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action1","Controller",null,new AjaxOption(){ onSuccess = "alert('=)')"},null)
{

   <intput type="submit" value="Save" />
}


Model2 model2 = new Model2();
@Html.EditorFor(m=>model2)
```

**In Model2 view i have. **

```
@model Model2 
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStreet","Controller",new AjaxOption(){onSuccess = "alert('=)'")},option,null)
{

        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Name):
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Name)

       <intput type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Thanks @Darin Dimitrov for answer.**

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That's because the second view is loaded with AJAX at a later stage and you need to call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(...)`
 immediately after its contents is injected into the DOM in order to enable unobtrusive validation. Look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for more details.

So in your case, instead of *alerting* in the `OnSuccess` callback of the first AJAX call, subscribe to a javascript function which will invoke this method:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Action1",
    "Controller",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
        UpdateTargetId = "result"
    },
    null)
)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and then in your javascript file:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    // enable unobtrusive validation for the contents
    // that was injected into the <div id="result"></div> node
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result));
};
```

Comment: @Sasha, in your second form you don't seem to include any input fields to be posted other than the submit button. So you are not sending anything to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: in action i take model2.Name ... and X-Requested-With

Comment: Try replacing `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name)` with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`. Same for the label and the validation.

Comment: The Ajax.BeginForm still invoking the post method of action.

Comment: Hi all , i have done same thing as Darin answered , still not working. Any help please. One more thing in my case that i am rendering partial view in modal popup(bootstrap-modal.js)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whey this method didn't work for me, the 'result' contained my dynamic form and no js errors were thrown by the parse method but validation did not work. I ended up passing in 'document' to the parse function and ignoring the 'result' entirely. Maybe this will help someone else?

Comment: `$(result)` did not work for me, instead I used `$("#result")`. Or one can also use 
`new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#result'));" }`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I added your solution to my code and i works perfectly but now an annoying js error "TypeError: owner is undefined" is popping up every time. any solution?

Answer (score 29):

You need to add those 2 files in you **Partial View** even if it is already in the **Shared/_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or place this in your **Partial**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
</script>
```

Comment: why need to put both on Layout and the PartialView?

Comment: its because the validation won't work, shorthand method : call it again.. Effective but not ideal

Comment: @dperez , I added your solution to my code and i works perfectly but now an annoying js error "TypeError: owner is undefined" is popping up every time. any solution?

Comment: I've done this before, but I believe when I added jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to both _Layout and the partial view, the form was getting submitted twice.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked best for me.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Darin Dimitrov only works when `validate()` of the `jquery validate plugin` has not been called until the Ajax success handler is called. I can't think of a scenario where this could be the case, thus i wonder why the answer was accepted as correct.

Perhaps a change in the jquery validate code in the past now causes the following issue:

The issue is that `validate()` executes the following line first

```
// Check if a validator for this form was already created
var validator = $.data( this[ 0 ], "validator" );
if ( validator ) {
  return validator;
```

which means that the **validator object is returned when validate() is called without and further handling of the options passed**.

This also means that a later call to `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(...)` or `$.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement(...)` which executes a

```
$form.validate(this.options) <- this.options holds the new rules parsed from HTML
```

to update the options of the validator has no effect because the options are not processed at all.

The solution here is to update the validator manually like

```
var $htmlCode = $("your html");

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($htmlCode, true); // true means no validate() call

// now get the validation info collected in parse()
var validationInfo = $form.data("unobtrusiveValidation"); 

var $validator = $form.validate(); // get validator and ...
$validator.settings.rules = validationInfo.options.rules; // ... update its rules
$validator.settings.messages = validationInfo.options.messages; // ... update its messages
```

Revalidating the form (e.g. clicking submit) should now result in the expected results.

Here is a full example witch also includes code from the already accepted answer:

*Razor*

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Action1",
    "Controller",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
        UpdateTargetId = "result"
    },
    null)
)
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

*Javascript*

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    var $htmlCode = $(result);

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($htmlCode, true); // true means no validate() call

    // now get the validation info collected in parse()
    var validationInfo = $form.data("unobtrusiveValidation"); 

    var $validator = $form.validate(); // get validator and ...
    $validator.settings.rules = validationInfo.options.rules; // ... update its rules
    $validator.settings.messages = validationInfo.options.messages; // ... update its messages
};
```

--

As a side note, manually updating the validator is also possible by using the `rules()` method like

```
$yourHtmlField.rules( "add", {
  required: true,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input"
  }
});
```

as this directly updates the rules of the validator without the unobtrusive stuff. But then the data-val attributes are rendered useless.

Comment: Can you give a full example for this so we don't have to splice together different bits of your solution?

Comment: @Pangamma Done, i was basically only referring to the answer of *Darin Dimitrov*.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a reference to `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` to enable the validation within `Ajax Form`

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Sasha, in View2 you didn't end the string `"alert('=)')` => `"alert('=)')"`

Comment: it's not it... I can't show full code.. Because it large. I think that i must use i frame and show View2 in frame.