# Client side data annotation is not working on partial views that containe ajax.beginform inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

i have the following partial view that will be returned after clicking on the ajax.actionlink:-

```
@model System.Models.Answer 
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Create"; 
} 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id = "partialWrapper">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Answer", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "incrementanswer",
    OnSuccess = "removePartial"
}))

 {
     <div id = "returnedquestion">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Answer here</legend> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div>  
    </fieldset> 
     <input type= "hidden" name = "questionid" value = @ViewBag.questionid>
     <input type= "hidden" name = "assessmentid" value = @ViewBag.assessmentid>
     <input type="submit" value="Add answer" />
 </div>
 }
 </div>
```

**the problme is that if i click on the submit button while leaving the required fileds empty then no client side validation will be displayed that the IsRight and the description fields are required, instead a whole view (containing the layout )will be returned,,  so what might be the problem?**

here is the action method that is being called from the partila view:-

```
[HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Create(int questionid, Answer a) 
        { 
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            { 
        repository.AddAnswer(a); 
             repository.Save(); 
             return PartialView("_details",a); 
            } 
            return View(a);
```

and the ajax.actionlink that will return the partial view:-

```
<div id ="link">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Answer", "Create", "Answer",
        new { questionid = Model.QuestionID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {

              HttpMethod = "Get",
              UpdateTargetId = "link",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
              LoadingElementId = "progress"


                        })
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind Unobtrusive JavaScript in the success part of the ajax request. As below:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(“div#divWizard”));
```

Please review the following [link to my blog](http://deepakkushvah.wordpress.com/) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable unobtrusive validation?

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
 </appSettings>
```

Did you link those script files appropriately?

```
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"><script>
```

Comment: yes i can see all of these scripts fired succsfully under the Script Document section after i run the application, i also moved the Jquery.validate script into the partial view instead of being on the main view and the problem did not solve.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be what you're looking for: [Unobtrusive validation doesn't work with Ajax.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937994/93356)